# not printing correct character array C

Tags: c, for-loop, printf

I am trying to print a minesweeper board.

Currently, it will only print 0's and where the bomb locations are but not the amount of adjacent bombs.  I think it has to do with the location of my braces, but I am unsure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int width, tall, W;
    int T=1;
    int g;
    int c=0;
    printf("How wide do you want your board?\n Max 32 squares\n");
    scanf("%d",&width);
    printf("How tall do you want your board?\n Max 32 squares\n");
    scanf("%d",&tall);
    printf("How many mines do you want?\n Between 0 and 1000 please\n");
    scanf("%d",&W);
    int y= tall*width;
    if (width>32 || width <=0 || tall>32 || tall <=0)
        {
            printf("Error, not valid dimensions\n");
            T=0;
        }
    if (W>1000 || W<0 || W>(tall*width))
        {
            printf("Error, not a valid amount of mines\n");
            T=0;
        }
    if (T==0)
        {
            printf("Sorry, you cannot play Mine sweeper!\n");
        }
    char array[tall][width];
    int i,j;
    if (T==1)
        {
            for(i=0;i<tall;i++)
                {
                    for(j=0;j<width;j++)
                        {
                            g=rand() % y;
                            if (g<=W)
                                {
                                    array[i][j]='*';
                                }
                            if(g>W)
                                {
                                    array[i][j]='0';
                                }
                        }
                }

            for(i=0;i<tall;i++)
                {
                    for(j=0;j<width;j++)
                        {
                            if(array[i][j]==0)
                                {
                                    if(array[i-1][j-1]=='*')
                                        {
                                            c=c+1;
                                        }
                                    if(array[i][j-1]=='*')
                                        {
                                            c=c+1;
                                        }
                                    if (array[i+1][j-1]=='*')
                                        {
                                            c=c+1;
                                        }
                                    if (array[i-1][j]=='*')
                                        {
                                            c=c+1;
                                        }
                                    if (array[i+1][j]=='*')
                                        {
                                            c=c+1;
                                        }
                                    if (array[i-1][j+1]=='*')
                                        {
                                            c=c+1;
                                        }
                                    if (array[i][j+1]=='*')
                                        {
                                            c=c+1;
                                        }
                                    if (array[i+1][j+1]=='*')
                                        {
                                            c=c+1;
                                        }
                                    switch(c)
                                        {
                                        case 0:
                                            {
                                                array[i][j]=' ';
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        case 1:
                                            {
                                                array[i][j]='1';
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        case 2:
                                            {
                                                array[i][j]='2';
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        case 3:
                                            {
                                                array[i][j]='3';
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        case 4:
                                            {
                                                array[i][j]='4';
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        case 5:
                                            {
                                                array[i][j]='5';
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        case 6:
                                            {
                                                array[i][j]='6';
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        case 7:
                                            {
                                                array[i][j]='7';
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        case 8:
                                            {
                                                array[i][j]='8';
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }

            for(i=0;i<tall;i++)
                {
                    for(j=0;j<width;j++)
                        {
                            printf("%c",array[i][j]);
                        }
                    printf("\n");
                }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You access outside the array bounds. When `i = 0`, you shouldn't access `array[i-1]`. And when `j = 0`, you shouldn't access `array[...][j-1]`. And there are similar problems with `i+1` and `j+1` when you're at the other extremes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three problems:
1. As Barmar said you need to restrict the access to the array. Just check in the if-clauses whether `i` or `j` are some extreme value (0 or `tall-1` resp. `width-1`).
2. You are comparing the value of an char with an integer in

```
if(array[i][j]==0)
```

In your case that always evaluates to false so you didn't even enter that part of the code.
3. You don't reset your counter `c` to `0` after you are done with one location.

Corrected code for that part

```
for(i=0;i<tall;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
        c = 0;
        if(array[i][j]=='0'){
            if(i != 0 && j != 0 && array[i-1][j-1]=='*'){
                c=c+1;
            }
            if(j != 0 && array[i][j-1]=='*'){
                c=c+1;
            }
            if (i != tall-1 && j != 0 && array[i+1][j-1]=='*'){
                c=c+1;
            }
            if (i != 0 && array[i-1][j]=='*'){
                c=c+1;
            }
            if (i != tall-1 && array[i+1][j]=='*'){
                c=c+1;
            }
            if (i != 0 && j != width-1 && array[i-1][j+1]=='*'){
                c=c+1;
            }
            if (j != width-1 && array[i][j+1]=='*'){
                c=c+1;
            }
            if (i != tall-1 && j != width-1 && array[i+1][j+1]=='*'){
                c=c+1;
            }
            switch(c){
                case 0:{
                    array[i][j]='0';
                    break;
                }
                case 1:{
                    array[i][j]='1';
                    break;
                }
                case 2:{
                    array[i][j]='2';
                    break;
                }
                case 3:{
                    array[i][j]='3';
                    break;
                }
                case 4:{
                    array[i][j]='4';
                    break;
                }
                case 5:{
                    array[i][j]='5';
                    break;
                }
                case 6:{
                    array[i][j]='6';
                    break;
                }
                case 7:{
                    array[i][j]='7';
                    break;
                }
                case 8:{
                    array[i][j]='8';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```